# Strategy for minimizing bank conflicts for 64-bit thread-separate shared memory

Tags: cuda, 64-bit, idioms, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict

Suppose I have a full warp of threads in a CUDA block, and each of these threads is intended to work with N elements of type T, residing in shared memory (so we have warp_size * N = 32 N elements total). The different threads never access each other's data. (Well, they do, but at a later stage which we don't care about here). This access is to happen in a loop such as the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < big_number; i++) {
    auto thread_idx = determine_thread_index_into_its_own_array();
    T value = calculate_value();
    write_to_own_shmem(thread_idx, value);
}
```

Now, the different threads may have different indices each, or identical - I'm not making any assumptions this way or that. But I do want to minimize shared memory bank conflicts.

If `sizeof(T) == 4`, then this is is easy-peasy: Just place all of thread i's data in shared memory addresses i, 32+i, 64+i, 96+i etc. This puts all of i's data in the same bank, that's also distinct from the other lane's banks. Great.

But now - what if `sizeof(T) == 8`? How should I place my data and access it so as to minimize bank conflicts (without any knowledge about the indices)?

Note: Assume T is plain-old-data. You may even assume it's a number if that makes your answer simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr: Use the same kind of interleaving as for 32-bit values.

On later-than-Kepler micro-architectures (up to Volta), the best we could theoretically get is 2 shared memory transactions for a full warp reading a single 64-bit value (as a single transaction provides 32 bits to each lane at most).

This is is achievable in practice by the analogous placement pattern OP described for 32-bit data. That is, for `T* arr`, have lane `i` read the `idx`'th element as `T[idx + i * 32]`. This will compile so that two transactions occur:

1. The lower 16 lanes obtain their data from the first 32*4 bytes in T (utilizing all banks)
2. The higher 16  obtain their data from the successive 32*4 bytes in T (utilizing all banks)

So the GPU is smarter/more flexible than trying to fetch 4 bytes for each lane separately. That means it can do better than the simplistic "break up T into halves" idea the earlier answer proposed.

<sub>(This answer is based on @RobertCrovella's comments.)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

On Kepler GPUs, this had a simple solution: Just change the bank size! Kepler supported setting the shared memory bank size to 8 instead of 4, dynamically. But alas, that feature is not available in later microarchitectures (e.g. Maxwell, Pascal).

Now, here's an ugly and sub-optimal answer for more recent CUDA microarchitectures: Reduce the 64-bit case to the 32-bit case.

- Instead of each thread storing N values of type `T`, it stores 2N values, each consecutive pair being the low and the high 32-bits of a `T`.
- To access a 64-bit values, 2 half-`T` accesses are made, and the `T` is composed with something like `

  ```
  uint64_t joined =
      reinterpret_cast<uint32_t&>(&upper_half) << 32  +
      reinterpret_cast<uint32_t&>(&lower_half);
  auto& my_t_value = reinterpret_cast<T&>(&joined);
  ```

  and the same in reverse when writing.

As comments suggest, it is better to make 64-bit access, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792867/1593077).

Comment: Your statement about Kepler is correct. On other architectures, just store and access the data the way you normally would. Your construct provides no value. The reason there is an 8-byte bank mode on Kepler and not the others is that Kepler provides 64 bits per bank per cycle throughput. That's not true of the others (read [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities)). With 32 bits per bank per cycle, typical full-warp accesses will get broken into 2 transactions for 8 byte quantities; your construct does not improve on that.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But there is no "normally" - I get to choose what's best. Now, I realize I won't get 64 bits per bank per cycle, but with my method I should at least get 32 bits per bank per cycle, while with conflicts I worry I'll get less than that due to bank collisions - as each lane must necessarily access 2 banks (and the accesses are all-even-banks, then all-odd-banks, if we respect alignment).

Comment: Your construct doesn't remove any bank conflict effects.  If two threads happened to access an 8 byte quantity in the same 2 banks (a properly aligned 8 byte quantity always occupies two 32-bit banks), your code will not sort it out.  In addition, it adds a bunch of unnecessary work such as shifts and adds.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Again, there is no "happened to access", and no previous conflicts. I need to decide which shared memory locations will be used by each lane for each index in its array - there is no existing access pattern... Using this method, though, I can make all 32-bit parts of a lane's data be in the same bank, getting around the alignment constraint.

Comment: So your expectation is that no matter what, you will have each thread write to a fixed column in memory.  And you believe that in the T=4 case, you will effectively have each thread in the warp assigned to a bank (column).  Great.  In the T=8 case, with a full warp, assign the "columns"  consecutively.  Thread 0 writes to i+0 and thread 31 writes to i+31.  (Also: thread 0 writes to i+0, i+32, etc. just as you have said.) You have assigned each thread a column in memory, it just happens to be a column that is 2 banks wide.  That is OK.

Comment: Yes, it will require 2 transactions (no bank conflicts) but your method requires 2 transactions also, and brings extra overhead and code complexity with it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Ah, Ok, now I get. So you're saying that if lane i reads 64 bits from banks 2*i and 2*i + 1 (a single 64-bit read), this will be executed in 2 transactions? Not 4?

Comment: The first 16 threads in the warp will occupy all 32 of the 32-bit banks, and that will be one transaction.  The second 16 threads in the warp will also occupy all 32 of the 32-bit banks, and that will be the second transaction.  For a given thread, the read from bank 2*i and 2*i+1 will happen *in the same transaction*.  That does not imply any sort of bank conflict, either.

Comment: The 64-bit access is 1 instruction resulting in two transactions. On Maxwell/Pascal this is a 2 cycle latency penalty. The 2 32-bit accesses are 2 instructions resulting in two transactions with at best case a 2 cycle latency. Since you are issuing two instructions you are using an extra issue cycle that another warp could have used. On Maxwell - Volta the 64-bit operation is the better choice.

Comment: @GregSmith: That makes sense. But this answer still has some merit, IMHO, since the hardware could have behaved different; and the principle is applicable to similar scenarios on other hardware.